# How many messages are send with System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send() if multiple recipients are specified?

Tags: .net, email, bandwidth

I have some code which uses `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send` to send data from a piece of software I maintain. We're charged on the amount of data we send so it's crucial that we identify the most cost effective way to distribute the information.

If I specify multiple recipients, am I right in thinking the software would be transmitting one email per recipient? i.e. if each email was 1MB and I had three recipients, I'd be sending 3MB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually when you send a mail with multiple recipients, your client sends **one** email to your provider and this is responsible to send one message to every recipient...
If you want to be sure, use [WireShark](http://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=wireshark&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wireshark.org%2F&ei=rk6ETrP3MYWwhQepndzpDA&usg=AFQjCNHE63N0oC3FKruR4eA0xdxI87juZg) to monitor SMTP port you use and check the traffic amount.

**EDITED:**
My previous answer was true if you have an external provider; situation can be different if you have an internal mail server in your company: in this case your server is responsible to send this email and, according to its configuration (using a smarthost, etc...), it could send a single email to an external provider or send multiple emails one for each recipient.
In this case you must check what happens on SMTP port of your server.

Comment: We're sending via an external provider (gmail). I was hoping not to have to do an experiment, but I'll give it a go :-)

Comment: @Jon Cage: If you use GMail I'm quite sure you're sending a single email message